# Postfix: disable authentication through port 25

Tags: postfix, smtp, imap, sasl

When  using `Postfix` and `IMAP` on a mailserver, at least 3 ports are usually opened

```
25 smtp   : incoming emails from anybody (whole internet)
465 smtps : outgoing emails from authorized users (to the whole intenet)
993 imap  : imap for authorized users
```

I would like to configure postfix, so that authorized users can only send email through 465. By default this is not so. Users can also use STARTTLS over port 25. I would like to disable that.

My plan is to use port 25 for the public sending me email

use port 465 for my users (I can use firewall to allow specific IP ranges, or use custom port)

This would prevent port 25 being exploitable from brute force attacks, where hackers try to guess user/password. Port 25 simply would not accept user/password, even if it were valid. And since port 465 is restricted by firewall, hackers cannot exploit 465 either.

Is this possible in Postfix?

I am using Postfix 2.9.6-2 on Debian Wheezy

Comment: I know this is old, but you should *always* allow port 587 (submission) as this is the proper port.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***WARNING:***
The request does not follow best security practice because you disable TLS (encryption) on your main mail relay port, exposing data sent through that port to third-party listeners and/or in-flight modification. The answer below satisfies the request, but best practice requires STARTTLS for the port 25 connection as well.

The `master.cf` file (usually `/etc/postfix/master.cf`) controls the startup and configuration of specific Postfix services. A configuration like this in that file, according to the documentation, will do what you want:

```
smtp  inet  n  -  -  -  -  smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no

smtps inet  n  -  -  -  -  smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

This configuration turns off authentication and the STARTTLS option on port 25. It turns on the STARTTLS option on port 465, requires STARTTLS usage, enables authentication, and only allows clients to connect if authenticated.

You might also look into the `smtpd_tls_wrappermode` option to force true TLS connections (and not STARTTLS connections).

Note that this kind of configuration can make the Postfix configuration somewhat difficult to follow (options may be set in `main.cf` and then overridden in `master.cf`). The other option is to run multiple instances of Postfix, each with their own `main.cf` configuration files that specify these options.

Comment: if conflicting options were set in `main.cf`, which ones would take preference? From what you say, it seems that `master.cf` overrides `main.cf`. Is this correct?

Comment: The `-o` options override those in the configuration files. The `master.cf` file coordinates the startup of processes, and if you were to startup the processes by hand with the `-o` options, they would override whatever the configuration file specified.

Comment: Won't `-o smtpd_tls_security_level=none` kill TLS/make everything plain text in case some server is trying to relay email or some other server-to-server SMTP connection to port 25?

Comment: The `-o smtpd_tls_security_level=none` will indeed prevent STARTTLS from working on port 25 and thus make all communication in plain-text. That is what the question requested.

Comment: I'm still downvoting this for the above reason. Complying with OP's request is fine, but you should add a capital-letter warning that is a very bad idea. (Please let me upvote you instead, by adding that. ;-) )

Comment: @ntninja Good suggestion. How does that message suit you?

Comment: Awesome! Well written and to the point!

Comment: This master.cf suggestion is misleading in the sense that `smtps` is typically the port that has `smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes`. `submissions` is the port, where you want `smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt` and `smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no`.